# Handle multiple servers trying to run migrations with 'migrationsRun' option

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

We have a NestJS v9 backend which uses typeorm v0.30.0 to communicate with a Postgres server. We have `migrationsRun` property set to `true` in our `DataSourceOptions`.

```js
export default new DataSource({
  ...
  migrationsRun: true,
});
```

We recently had this error in our logs:

```bash
query failed: ALTER TYPE "item_type_enum" RENAME TO "item_type_enum_old"
error: error: tuple concurrently updated
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
    at Parser.parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23) {
  length: 90,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: 'XX000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'heapam.c',
  line: '4268',
  routine: 'simple_heap_update'
}
Migration "changeItemTypeEnum1662924574480" failed, error: tuple concurrently updated
```

This is the migration:

```js
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
  await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TYPE "item_type_enum" RENAME TO "item_type_enum_old"`);
  await queryRunner.query(
    `CREATE TYPE "item_type_enum" AS ENUM('CLOTHING', 'FOOD', 'JEWELLERY', 'SPORTS')`,
  );

  await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "orders" ALTER COLUMN "item_type"
    SET DATA TYPE "item_type_enum"
      USING (
        CASE "item_type"::text
          WHEN '1' THEN 'CLOTHING'
          WHEN '2' THEN 'FOOD'
          WHEN '3' THEN 'JEWELLERY'
          WHEN '4' THEN 'SPORTS'
        END
      )::"item_type_enum";`);
  await queryRunner.query(`DROP TYPE "item_type_enum_old"`);
}
```

We have 3 replicas of our backend running inside 3 pods in a Kubernetes cluster. The requests from the frontend are routed to one of the pods which would contain a backend service. If a frontend sends multiple requests which are then routed to more than one backend pod, it is possible that more than one backend server would try to connect with the Postgres database server. As the error says, this could be because more than one of our backend servers is trying to create the connection with the Postgres database server and try to run the migrations simultaneously.

We use multi-tenancy database architecture (one database per client) and therefore, it is hard for us to have a separate service handling the migrations mainly because it would cause the deployment to take longer times.

Is there a way we can handle this issue?